How to solve constrained maximization of functional, uncountably infinite constraints
Given function $q(z \mid x)$, which is a probability density if it matters, I'm interested in maximizing the expectation of a functional $L$ of $q(\cdot \mid x)$ with respect to $x$: $\max_q \mathbb E_{p(x)}[L(q, x)]$, while ensuring $q(\cdot \mid x)$ is a probability density $\forall x \sim p(x)$. The density $p(x)$ is known. So it appears there are infinitely many equality constraints, one per each value of $x$. To stay simple, assume $x \in \mathbb R$.
Recall Lagrange multiplier; to maximize $f(x)$ given $K$ equality constraints $g_i(x)=0$, the Lagrangian is $f(x) + \sum_{i=1}^K \mu_i g_i(x)$. So without learning any variational calculus, I imagine in my setting, the Lagrangian is similarly: $\mathbb E_{p(x)}[L(q,x)]+\int \mu(x) (\int q(z \mid x)\,\mathrm dz-1)\,\mathrm dx$, where I use integral because there are infinitely many index $x$, in contrast to finitely many index $i$. Is that correct? If possible, it'd be great if there's any tutorial or online course on this specific problem, because I may not have enough time to go through an entire branch of theory. Thank you so much!

This setup is basically correct, but you need to know what sort of space $\int q(z \mid x),\mathrm dz-1$ lies in, since $\mu$ must be an element of its dual space

Do you mean the space $g(x) := \int q(z \mid x),\mathrm dz - 1$ lies in? Could you suggest an example of "the space" or point me to some reference? Sorry I'm really new to functionals. @whpowell96

For example, if $g$ is only integrable vs being square integrable, then this imposes restrictions on $\mu$ since the integral of their product has to exist. If this is your first time with this, I wouldn't worry too much about the function spaces. You will need to do some variational calculus though. Now that you have this, you should be able to differentiate everything and and obtain optimality conditions
